Zend Server web API always returns home page
I'm having this issue where no matter what I do, the zend server api always returns me this response when doing a POST request to the server
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div style="padding: 8px">
<span>Redirecting to <a href="/ZendServer/Login" target="_top">Login page</a>...</span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var newLocation = "/ZendServer/Login?redirectTo={uri}".replace("{uri}", encodeURIComponent(location.href));
    location = newLocation ;
</script>
</body>
</html>

This is the request I'm doing using Bruno
> POST http://my_ip:my_port/ZendServer/Api/vhostAdd
> X-Zend-Signature: my_api_key
> Date: Fri, 20 Dec 2024 13:32:30 GMT
> Host: my_ip:my_port
> User-Agent: Bruno
> content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> cookie: ZDEDebuggerPresent=php,phtml,php3
> data
name=vhost_name&port=vhost_port

The date of course is always changed using the current date and time in GMT timezone.
I've tried changing everything, tried sending the data via form encoded or via multipart form, but still I got that problem.
